# Automatic wrapped multiple line text with space between highlighted lines

Tags: html, css, frontend

Question regarding CSS.

I will receive sentences like: `This is a sentence` and I will automatically break it to new lines regarding the parent's container width. So, for example, I will have 
`This is
a sentence`
What I am trying to do can actually can be seen in this code example. The lines are highlighted but there is some space (with white color) between lines. When setting some color `background-color: black` I can't create such spaces changing `line-height`. I also tried setting `linear-gradient` as background but it doesn't work the way I wanted.

This can be done by wrapping lines in `span` tags, but I want to avoid additional backend work.

Is there any obvious solution I missed or is a little bit tricky?

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Some text and its wrapping</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for comments - I added a snippet, nothing fancy though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without backend work it is simply **not** possible - you need a wrapping element for the fixed width.

But you don't need extra elements for each line. Check this:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>This is a sentence.</h1>
</div>
```

Or you use pseudo elements:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

div:after {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline;
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<div data-content="This is a sentence."></div>
```

Comment: Well this is exactly what I needed. Can you explain me, why text in <h2> tag works differently than in <h2><span> tags?

Comment: Block elements like h2 will fill the full width and inline elements like span not. So thats why it is differently. If you set `display: inline` to h2 it will also work.